# Spring Thymeleaf: form validation not working

Tags: spring, forms, validation, thymeleaf

I have a simple sign-up form that I am trying to validate, without success. The form is bound to the bean "User" that has some javax.validation.constraints.

The BindingResult and the displaying of the error work properly when I manually reject a value, though they don't work as expected when, for example, the user doesn't fill a @NotBlank field. It simply ignores it, the BindingResult contains no errors and moves on.

Here is the code:

**The form**

```
<form th:action="@{/account/new}" th:object="${user}" method="post">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Nome:</td>
        <td><input type="text" th:field="*{name}" /></td>
        <td th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('name')}" th:errors="*{name}">Name Error</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Cognome:</td>
        <td><input type="text" th:field="*{lastname}" /></td>
        <td th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('lastname')}" th:errors="*{lastname}">Cognome Error</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Email:</td>
        <td><input type="email" th:field="*{email}" /></td>
        <td th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('email')}" th:errors="*{email}">Email Error</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Password:</td>
        <td><input type="password" th:field="*{password}" /></td>
        <td th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('password')}" th:errors="*{password}">Password Error</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><button type="submit">Invia</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

**The User bean**

```
import javax.validation.constraints.Email;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import java.util.Set;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class User {

    public enum Role {
        ADMIN, UTENTE;
    }

@Id private String id;
@NotBlank private String name;
@NotBlank private String lastname;
@Email private String email;
@NotBlank @NotEmpty private Set<Role> roles;
@NotBlank private String username;
@NotBlank @Size(min=8) private String password;
@NotBlank private boolean active;
```

}

**The Controller**

```
@PostMapping("/account/new")
public String saveUser(@Valid User user, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) throws Exception {
    userRepository.findByEmail(user.getEmail())
            .ifPresent( s -> {  bindingResult.rejectValue("email", "error.user",
                            "There is already a user registered with this email"); });

    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        model.addAttribute("user", user);
        return "registration";
    }

    userService.saveNewUser(user);
    return "registration-need-confirmation";
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: i think you should remove `model.addAttribute("user", user);` from `if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {` for your errors to be displayed

Comment: Thanks for the answer Asgarov, I tried but the problem persists

Comment: Try adding `@ModelAttribute("user")` to the `user` parameter, so you have `@Valid @ModelAttribute("user") User user`. And indeed remove the adding of the attribute to the model in the `if` statement. It is also best to use `return "redirect:registration-need-confirmation` if there was no error.